# Add a column matching other two columns, one contains representative values

Tags: python, pandas

I have three data frames as follows:

```
df1
col1 CAND_SNP
1     a1
1     a2
1     a3
1     a4
2     b1
3     c1
3     c2
3     c3

df2
col1 LEAD_SNP
1     a1
2     b1
3     c1
    


df3
snp col2
a3     x1
a21    x2
a31    x3
a41    x4
b11    x5
c11    x6
c21    x7
c31    x8
```

I need to match `CAND_SNP` of `df1` with `snp` of `df3` to populate a new column in `df2` with values `"yes"` or `"no"`. The match needs to be groupwise for `col1` of `df1`. In the above example, there are 3 groups in `col1` of `df1`. If any of these group's corresponding value in `CAND_SNP` matches with `snp` of `df3` then the new column of `df2` would be `"yes"` as below: Any help?

```
df2
    col1 LEAD_SNP   col3
    1     a1        Yes
    2     b1        No
    3     c1        No
```

Comment: what is the match?? `a1` and `x1`?

Comment: The match is `a1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can group `df1` by `col1` and look up whether a value of `col2` exists in `col1` of `df3`. Then merge with `df2`:

```
df1['col3'] = df1.groupby('col1')['CAND_SNP'].apply(lambda s: s.isin(df3['snp']))
df2 = df2.merge(df1.groupby('col1')['col3'].any(), left_on='col1', right_index=True, how='left')
```

And if you need `'Yes'`/`'No'` as values, use

```
df2.col3.map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Comment: It is not working. Actual column names are different. I am editing the question with actual column names.

Comment: @zillurrahman I've updated the column names. Does it work now?